# Dart aqueduct Error: Not found: 'dart:html'

Tags: dart, dart-html, aqueduct

I have been using aqueduct for a simple server that if it gets HTTP request, analyze it, and send an HTTP request to other apps. However, whenever I tried to import dart:HTML, it gives an error.

```
-- Aqueduct CLI Version: 3.3.0+1
-- Aqueduct project version: 3.3.0+1
-- Preparing...
*** Uncaught error
    IsolateSpawnException: Unable to spawn isolate: lib/controller/test_controller.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
  **** Stacktrace
  ****
```

I searched for answer on google, and i found that android sdk is not able to use dart:HTML. So i tried with

stagehand web-simple
webdev serve

to find out if installed sdk is able to use dart:HTML or not and it worked.
Is there any way that I could download dart web libraries(dart:HTML) on aqueduct? If it is not possible, is there any other way that I could perform these actions?

Comment: Why exactly do you need dart:HTML? post example usage

Comment: Do not import web-only libraries in code that is supposed to run in mobile.